# Parse an MSMQ path to get destination computer address

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, msmq

Is there anything already provided in the .NET framework or the Win32 API for parsing an MSMQ path?  I simply need to get the destination computer's network address from an MSMQ path string.  I was hoping there would be a simple class similar to the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class, or something, but if there is, I can't seem to find it.  For instance:

- `Formatname:DIRECT=TCP:192.168.1.1\private$\MyQueueName` --> `192.168.1.1`
- `Formatname:DIRECT=OS:MyComputerName\private$\MyQueueName` --> `MyComputerName`

I know I can parse if myself with the String methods or RegEx, but I was hoping there might be a tool that already properly supports all the variations of the MSMQ path syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [runtime callable wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) around mqoa30.tlb

This can be found in system32 folder (or wow64)

Then you can create an instance of MSMQManagement object and call the [Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Would this be any different than just creating a `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` object and then accessing the `Machine` property from that?  It seems like the same thing, and the `MessageQueue` class has the advantage of being managed code.  It's an interesting option, but it seems go beyond simple parsing.  It seems to actually open the queue and fails if, for instance, the queue doesn't exist.

Comment: Steve you may be right - I was assuming you were not able to access the machine name from managed code.